# Rails 3 - reject_if proc not catching blank fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting rejected by reject_if.

The Item model has_many variants, with the model also accepting nested attributes:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants, :allow_destroy => :true,
  :reject_if => :all_blank
```

When I submit, it posts the following parameters:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"66areo4waM82H66771RkUD/Zt3rrp8Hgk/mwOqV42YI=", "item"=>{"name"=>"Dans", "body"=>"adsdsa", "visible"=>"1", "sellable"=>"0", "variants_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"", "price"=>"", "qty"=>"", "sku"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Save Item", "id"=>"6"}
```

For reference the controller:

```
  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.variants.build
```

The variants attributes are blank, but they aren't being rejected by the item model. So all the validations come through, making it unable to save. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `build` on association doesn't have anything to do with `reject_if` options of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. You call `build` without any parameters so it initializes variant with default attributes values.

Using `reject_if` matter when you initialize or update your parent model like that passing attributes for association models (variants) directly to parent model (item):

```
item = Item.new :name => "Dans", :variants_attributes => { "0" => { :name => "" } }
```

If `reject_if` is false you'll get new item with one variant having empty name. If `reject_if` is `true` this variant won't be created as all attributes passed are blank. But using this option do not prevent you from creating variants with blank attributes manually using `build` or directly adding variants to the item like that:

```
item.variants << Variant.new
```

Btw, why do you call `build` in your `edit` action? Usually `edit` action just fetches the model and renders the form. Updating attributes of a model happens in `update` action like that:

```
@item = Item.find params[:id]
@item.update_attributes params[:item]
```